# B&W animation in which old Asian lady finds huge ship

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation, black-and-white

I am looking for a colorless animation movie in which I only remember a scene: **an Asian looking old woman comes across a huge ship**. I think there were no sounds. The movie should be at least 5 years old. I know this is a very little info but that's all I remember.

Comment: Short or feature length? Did the animation look old or fairly recent?

Comment: Can you describe the ship she found? Anything else, any miniscule detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might it have been [The Triplets of Belleville](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286244/) from 2003?

There most certainly is a huge ship in it...
[image]

seen by a vaguely Asian-looking old woman...
[image]

and there is some black and white in the film...
[image]

Any of this ringing any bells?

Comment: you are great!!